# Unity ignores some blendshape vertices

Tags: shape-keys

Going on about 10 hours with this bug and wanted to throw it out to the community before I submit a bug report.

On my particular mesh (attached), Blender handles the shapekeys just fine. Everything that is supposed to move, does.

However when importing to Unity about half of the vertices are "locked" in position while everything else moves. It looks terrible. See photos.
[image] [image]

Changing Unity Normals to Calculate "fixes" the issue of vertices not moving. Unfortunately this is not a solution for me because the shaders I use bug out majorly with calculated normals. I need Import normals just like on my other 50 or so models where it works fine.

Things I've tried:
Deforming the mesh shapekeys (Transform, Scale, Rotate) in blender then exporting to unity
Copy and pasting the vertices and deleting the old ones
Copy and pasting vertices in to new projects
Mixing new shapekeys from existing shapekeys
New unity project
Hours upon hours of google searches

Possibly related topics:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/pro...n-blendshapes-via-blender-are-present.250279/
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/blendshapes-do-not-update-normal-directions
https://forum.unity.com/threads/model-how-to-set-normals-tangents.291436/
https://forum.unity.com/threads/deformed-geometry-shading-normals-wrong.347962/
https://developer.blender.org/T46019

I know the issue only manifests itself in Unity but I've exported countless times from Blender with no issue before that the problem must originate in Blender.

I can upload the mesh if somebody tells me where to post it since I cant attach it to the post.

Comment: Are you using an armature in Blender? If I edit my armature in Blender, for example delete a bone, it will mess up my character's mesh in Unity and I'm forced to delete the object and place it again into my scene.

Answer (score 0):

ok idk why this happens but I had the same issue and it took me a while to fix it but the problem is basically that if a vertice does not move enough in the blendshape it does not move at all in unity I found a janky workaround however go to scale factor in the fbx model options and set it to something high like 100 then if the model is in the scene set the scale to 0.01 to reverse the scaling in the model options then it should work fyi scaling in blender does not do the same thing[image: change this to something like 100]